# How to prevent the "@" from being added to my desired .Formula value?

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I have this workbook that requires an add-in to execute a psychrometric formula. The workgroup wants to be able to share this workbook with others via email. When you email the workbook, excel writes a path in front of the psychrometric formula command that is a link to the sender's desktop (or whatever location they've saved the add-in). To overwrite that link, I wrote some code in "This Workbook" under "Sub Workbook_Open()" (to run at start-up), that rewrites the formulas in the cells that use the psychrometric formula.

```
Dim rowIndex As Integer
rowIndex = 14

While (Sheet4.Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value <> "") 'should stop when value in column L is empty string. 

Sheet4.Cells(rowIndex, "L").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(C14="""","""",enthalpy(A14,14.7,IF(C14=""WB (F)"",1,IF(C14=""DP (F)"",2,IF(C14=""RH (%) as decimal"",3,IF(C14=""HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)"",4)))),D14,FALSE)),"""")"

Sheet4.Cells(rowIndex, "M").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(L14="""","""",enthalpy(B14,14.7,IF(C14=""WB (F)"",1,IF(C14=""DP (F)"",2,IF(C14=""RH (%) as decimal"",3,IF(C14=""HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)"",4)))),E14,FALSE)),"""")"

Sheet4.Cells(rowIndex, "O").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(I14="""","""",enthalpy(G14,14.7,IF(I14=""WB (F)"",1,IF(I14=""DP (F)"",2,IF(I14=""RH (%) as decimal"",3,IF(I14=""HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)"",4)))),J14,FALSE)),"""")"

Sheet4.Cells(rowIndex, "P").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(O14="""","""",enthalpy(H14,14.7,IF(I14=""WB (F)"",1,IF(I14=""DP (F)"",2,IF(I14=""RH (%) as decimal"",3,IF(I14=""HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)"",4)))),K14,FALSE)),"""")"


rowIndex = rowIndex + 1

Wend
```

What I start out with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(O14="","",'C:\Users\first.last\OneDrive - Consulting Inc\Documents\Excel add in\PSYCH.XLA'!enthalpy(H14,14.7,IF(I14="WB (F)",1,IF(I14="DP (F)",2,IF(I14="RH (%) as decimal",3,IF(I14="HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)",4)))),K14,FALSE)),"")
```

What I want:

```
=IFERROR(IF(O14="","",enthalpy(H14,14.7,IF(I14="WB (F)",1,IF(I14="DP (F)",2,IF(I14="RH (%) as decimal",3,IF(I14="HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)",4)))),K14,FALSE)),"")
```

What I get:

```
=IFERROR(@IF(O14="","",enthalpy(H14,14.7,IF(I14="WB (F)",1,IF(I14="DP (F)",2,IF(I14="RH (%) as decimal",3,IF(I14="HR (lbs H2O/lbs dry air)",4)))),K14,FALSE)),"")
```

What can I do to get rid of that '@', or is my approach to blame?

Comment: Use `.Formula2` if you are only using this code in Office 365.  If it will be used in other instances then use `.FormulaArray`

Comment: .FormulaArray rewrote adjacent cells as well. But .Formula2 produces the desired effect in the specified ranges. Thanks!